# Referring to the ChildSelector with keyword 'this' inside a function code in on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The issue:**
Keyword this refers to the primary selector upon which on() method is attached to, but I want it to refer to the selector that is being clicked.
Also, click event fires both on input field and button instead of only the specified selector *.izbrisi* (a button). **Goal** is to remove the *div* with a class *input-group* when button with a class *izbrisi* is clicked.

I am studying this in one my of courses and I am required to use this variation of code specifically, but I can't make it work. Thus, please do not alter the code in a way that it is completely different. Thank you.

```js
$("#brojevi-polja").on("click", $(".izbrisi"), function() {
    $(this).closest(".input-group").remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="brojevi-polja" class="col-4">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" class="izbrisi">Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" class="izbrisi">Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" class="izbrisi">Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" class="izbrisi">Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate problems:

1. You're calling [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) incorrectly. To do event delegation, the second argument should be a string containing a CSS seletor, not a jQuery object. So change

   ```
   $("#brojevi-polja").on("click", $(".izbrisi"), function()
   ```

   to

   ```
   $("#brojevi-polja").on("click", ".izbrisi", function()
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. You have two `class` attributes on the `izbrisi` elements:

   ```html
   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" class="izbrisi">Izbriši</button>
   <!--    ^^^^^                                           ^^^^^                        -->
   ```

   You can't do that, it's invalid HTML. Only the first one is used, the second is completely ignored. Instead:

   ```html
   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary izbrisi" type="button">Izbriši</button>
   <!--    ^^^^^                            ^^^^^^^                             -->
   ```

If you fix those, it works:

```js
$("#brojevi-polja").on("click", ".izbrisi", function() {
    $(this).closest(".input-group").remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="brojevi-polja" class="col-4">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary izbrisi" type="button">Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary izbrisi" type="button">Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary izbrisi" type="button">Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary izbrisi" type="button">Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There few things wrong

1 You have 2 class attribute on your buttons
2 you are using a jquery selector in the click listener

this works

```js
$("#brojevi-polja").on("click", ".izbrisi", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   
    $(this).closest(".input-group").remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="brojevi-polja" class="col-4">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary izbrisi" type="button" >Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary izbrisi" type="button" >Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary izbrisi" type="button" >Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="broj" aria-label="Recipient's username"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary izbrisi" type="button" >Izbriši</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```